# Застрял с JQUERY

Tags: jquery, css3, html5

При клике на лайк он становится красным, при втором клике я хочу снять красный цвет с лайка.

JS:

```
$(function() {
  $(".like_1_desctop").click(function() {
    $(".like_1_desctop").css("margin-top", "-66px");
  });
});
```

CSS:

```
.customSprite:hover,
.customSprite:active {
  margin-top: -66px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="customSprite max like_1_desctop">
  <img class="" src="img/dekstop_like_custom_1.png" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: $(".like_1_desctop").click(function() { $(".like_1_desctop").toggleClass("active"); });

Comment: не очень понятно, я новичок

Comment: вместо того чтобы сразу писать css в дж будет меняться класс "active" на который напишете 
.customSprite:hover,
.customSprite:active,
.customSprite.active {
  margin-top: -66px;
}

Comment: спасибо вам, я понял

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.like_1_desctop').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.like_1_desctop {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.like_1_desctop.active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="customSprite max like_1_desctop">
  
</div>
```